# How to use two carousels in a tab panel?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html, css, plugins

I need help in managing two different post carousel under tab panel. I am using post carousel shortcode under two tab link. So each carousel should appear under the tab link. And I am using a WordPress plugin for making the post carousel name  Responsive Posts Carousel. And using this code for tab initially.

The problem is that initially the active tab displaying the first carousel properly. But when I am clicking the 2nd tab, it shows the 2nd carousel with a `width:0px`.

Here is [the page link](http://kjustice.jjcreative.info/RealEstate/home-version2/). You will see two tab section name "Home" and "Profile".

```css
.nav-tabs { border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD; }
    .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover { border-width: 0; }
    .nav-tabs > li > a { border: none; color: #666; }
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li > a:hover { border: none; color: #4285F4 !important; background: transparent; }
        .nav-tabs > li > a::after { content: ""; background: #4285F4; height: 2px; position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0px; bottom: -1px; transition: all 250ms ease 0s; transform: scale(0); }
    .nav-tabs > li.active > a::after, .nav-tabs > li:hover > a::after { transform: scale(1); }
.tab-nav > li > a::after { background: #21527d none repeat scroll 0% 0%; color: #fff; }
.tab-pane { padding: 15px 0; }
.tab-content{padding:20px}

.card {background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%; box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); margin-bottom: 30px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <!-- Nav tabs --><div class="card">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>

                                    </ul>

                                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">[wcp-carousel id="1596"] </div>
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">[wcp-carousel id="1593"] </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
</div>
                                </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it sounds like the issue might have to do with initializing the carousel when the section it is going to be displayed in is hidden or has width:0.  IIRC, in those cases, the js initializing the carousel won't be able to find the width it needs to use.  Try either reinitializing the carousel to when you click on the 2nd tab, or delaying the initialization of each carousel until the user needs to see them.

Comment: Hi Chris, 

Thanks, If you could explain a bit more how I can do this, it will greatly be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

**use this css**

```
<style>
 .tab-content > .tab-pane {
display:  block !important;
order: 1;
width:  100%;
opacity: 0;
}

.tab-content {
 display:  flex;
 width:  100%;
 flex-wrap:  wrap;
  } 
   .tab-content > .tab-pane.active {
    order: 0;
   position:  absolute;
   opacity:  1;
}
 </style>
```